# How to set Qt sRGB gamma for stylesheets and labels?

Tags: qt, opengl, srgb

My `QGLWidget` has `glEnable(GL_FRAMEBUFFER_SRGB)` but my Qt widgets are not gamma corrected causing a disconnect between the Qt stylesheet colors and other colors (for color picking) and what is displayed in the QGL view.

Is there a Qt way to  gamma correct in these cases?

Comment: Use only black and white

Comment: USe only black and white :)